# What is appropriate when a binomial regression DV is determined by some levels of a categorical regression predictor variable?

Tags: regression, logistic

A binary logistic regression outcome variable is defined with reference to an age criterion. The binary outcome is 'Early death'=1 -- meaning the person died (in a follow-up observation period) before reaching age 65. All subjects have the same observation period. At the start of the observation period, the age of all subjects is known. I intend to use several regression predictor variables. One of the regression predictors will be a categorical age variable. It has 6 categories. Two of the category levels are 65-74 years old and 75 and above. Any person who was 65-74 or 75+ at the start of the observation period, and died in the observation period, could not have experienced the regression outcome, early death, because they were too old; they were not 64 or younger. If they died in the observation period, their value of the dependent variable is necessarily 0 (did not experience an early death). Consequently, the dependent variable's value is determined by age for these two age category levels (65-74 and 75+); the dependent variable must be 0. But the dependent variable can be 0 or 1 for any other age category that is 64 and less.

Question: is it advisable to exclude from the regression model observations where the person's age is => 65? Or should they be retained in the model? (And not interpret the parameter estimates for the age categories => 65.)

Comment: I very, very. very much recommend you look into *survival analysis*. A simple logistic regression that does not account for censoring is inappropriate here.

Comment: I would also recommend looking into "immortal time bias", which is a bias that occurs when you only include that have survived long enough to be in your study, which is the case here.